# Htaccess how do I rewrite a space to a hyphen for a specific dynamic url

Tags: .htaccess, url, replace, url-rewriting

How do I rewrite the following dynamic URL in htaccess :

`resort.php?location=$location`

When the `$location` is, for example, `las vegas` or `san francisco` I want to URL to be rewritten to:

`resort.php?location=las-vegas`

In summary I need to replace the whitespace with a hyphen but only on this URL.

hI, I want resort.php?location=las-vegas to show in the browser but las vegas is the variable $location thanks

Comment: What URL do you want to show in browser?

Comment: hI, I want resort.php?location=las-vegas to show in the browser but las vegas is the variable $location thanks